# Building a PrimeReact Menu from a function has TS error

Tags: typescript, primereact

I am looking to build a menu based on the items from a database.

I am getting the TS error:
Type '() => MenuItem[]' is not assignable to type 'MenuItem[]'

```
const model2 = ():MenuItem[] => {
    
     let items:MenuItem[] = [
        { label: 'New'},
    { label: 'Delete'} ];
    return items;
};

return <Menu model={model2} />;
```

Please let me know how to address this TS error.

Comment: _Call_ the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function with return

```
<Menu model={model2()} />;
```